# Countif value is unique and occurs in given month

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a sheet that tracks form responses and I'd like to add up the number of new users each month. I thought I could achieve this with a COUNTIFS formula like this:

```
=COUNTIFS('Form responses 1'!A1:A,"<01/02/2018",'Form responses 1'!B1:B,UNIQUE('Form responses 1'!B1:B))
```

So far I haven't had any success. Because it's a form response, column A is a timestamp and column B is the user's email address:

```
Timestamp             Email Address
01/01/2018 09:00:12   user1@email.com
03/01/2018 10:15:31   user2@email.com
06/01/2018 13:03:53   user3@email.com
11/01/2018 09:43:11   user2@email.com
15/01/2018 11:26:09   user1@email.com
20/01/2018 09:00:12   user3@email.com
```

I want a formula that will give the number of new users for each month in separate cells like this:

```
Month       New Users
January             3
February            6
March              10
etc.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=QUERY(
QUERY({A:B},"select Col2, min(Col1) group by Col2"), 
"select year(Col2), month(Col2)+1, count(Col1) group by year(Col2), month(Col2)+1 
label year(Col2) 'Year', month(Col2)+1 'Month', count(Col1) 'Count New'")`

- query #1 (inner): find the minimal date for each name
- query #2: count names by dates (year + month)